# VS2015 "no symbols loaded for this document" for .lib file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, dll, lib

I have an issue where I have a .dll file that is compiled in debug. It statically links with a .lib file, which is also compiled in debug. The source is available for all of them. However when I run the .dll and attach VS to the process it can only step through the .dll's own function but not the ones in the .lib.

In the module view I can see that symbols are loaded for all the modules. How can ensure that .lib has symbols associated with it as well? As I understand because it is linked statically the symbols for it should be generated when compiling the "parent" .dll, is that correct? So is there something I need to do when building the .dll to make sure that ALL functions can be stepped through?

Comment: Information about the library will be contained in a .pdb file.

Comment: The linker normally generates a warning for such a mishap.  Typically LNK4099, sometimes LNK4204.  Take a closer look when you rebuild the DLL.  Without a decent build trace it just takes random guessing, something you can see but we can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the location of the pdb file of the LIB you just built for the debugger to find the symbols in the appropriate `Tools/Options` section (usually the same directory as the output LIB).

[image: Enter your .pdb file path in here]

Then, you can add the location of the source files in the according `Solution Property` page :

[image: Place the directory for source files here]

Then, Visual Studio debugger will find all appropriate information. It will load symbols and be able to jump into the LIB source code when appropriate.